# StreamCorruptedException occurs during object decoding

Tags: java, nio, netty

I am writing a netty client and server application that will write JVM GC stats to a time-series database to analyse for around 300 servers.  However my pipeline is throwing lots of these exceptions:

```
10/02/2012 10:14:23.415 New I/O server worker #2-2 ERROR GCEventsCollector - netty error
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 6E
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder.decode(ObjectDecoder.java:94)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It looks like it's creating an OutputStream but one already exists - so it throws that specific exception. It appears in my AIT environment where >300 servers are connecting but not in DEV where 1 agent is only connecting.

I suspect it is either a bug in the object decoder or I have incorrect code somewhere. Please could anyone explain why this happens?

Here is the collector:

public class GCEventsCollector extends AbstractDataCollector {
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GCEventsCollector.class);
    private static final ExecutorService WORKERS = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static final ChannelGroup GROUP = new DefaultChannelGroup("gc-events");
    private final int port;
    private final ServerBootstrap bootstrap;

```
public GCEventsCollector(final int port) {
  logger.info("Creating GC Events collector on port " + port);
    this.port = port;
    this.bootstrap = newServerBootstrap(port);
}



/**
 * Creates a bootstrap for creating bindings to sockets. Each channel has a pipeline, which contains the
 * logic for handling a message such as encoding, decoding, buffering, etc.
 *
 * @param port port of socket
 * @return configured bootstrap
 */
private ServerBootstrap newServerBootstrap(int port) {
    ExecutorService bossExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ExecutorService workerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    NioServerSocketChannelFactory channelFactory =
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossExecutor, workerExecutor);
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelFactory);
    ChannelHandler collectorHandler = new CollectorHandler();
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new CollectorPipelineFactory(collectorHandler));
    bootstrap.setOption("localAddress", new InetSocketAddress(port));
    return bootstrap;
}

protected KDBCategory[] getKDBCategories() {
    return new KDBCategory[] { KDBCategory.GC_EVENTS };
}

/**
 * Bind to a socket to accept messages
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void doStart() throws Exception {
    Channel channel = bootstrap.bind();
    GROUP.add(channel);
}

/**
 * Disconnect the channel to stop accepting messages and wait until disconnected
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void doStop() throws Exception {
    logger.info("disconnecting");
    GROUP.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
}

class CollectorHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    @Override
    public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
            throws Exception {          
        super.channelOpen(ctx, e);
        GROUP.add(e.getChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
            ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {         
        super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
        logger.info("channel connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
            ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        super.channelDisconnected(ctx, e);
        logger.info("channel disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
          logger.debug("Received GcStats event: " + e.toString());
    }
        WORKERS.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        saveData(KDBCategory.GC_EVENTS, (GcEventsPersister) e.getMessage());
    }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        logger.error("netty error", e.getCause());
    }
}

private static class CollectorPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    private final ChannelHandler handler;

    private CollectorPipelineFactory(ChannelHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        return Channels.pipeline(new ObjectDecoder(), handler);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the agent:

```
public class GCEventsAgent {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GCEventsAgent.class);
    private static final ExecutorService bosses = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static final ExecutorService workers = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static final Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
    private static final String localHostName;
    private static final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener = new   ExceptionListener();

static {
    String name = "";
    try {
        name = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        logger.error("cannot retrieve local host name", e);
    }
    localHostName = name;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    checkArgument(args.length >= 3, "Usage: GCEventsAgent [log4j cfg] [mba cfg] [server cfg] [process 1] ... [process n]");

    System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", "file:log4j.properties");
    final String log4jConfig = args[0];
    DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jConfig);

    final String mbaConfig = args[1];

    final String serverConfigPath = args[2];
    final ServerConfig serverCfg = new ServerConfig(serverConfigPath);

    setup(serverCfg, args);
}

private static void setup(ServerConfig cfg, String[] args) {
    final String host = cfg.getParameter(String.class, "host");
    final int port = cfg.getParameter(Integer.class, "port");
    if (args.length == 3)
        configurePolling(cfg, host, port);
    else
        configureProcesses(cfg, args, host, port);
}

private static void configureProcesses(final ServerConfig cfg,
                                       final String[] args,
                                       final String host,
                                       final int port) {
    final List<File> logFiles = logFiles(cfg, args);
    logger.info("Initializing GC Agent for [" + host + ":" + port + "]");

    final NioClientSocketChannelFactory channelFactory =
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(bosses, workers);
    final ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);
    bootstrap.setOption("remoteAddress", new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    final GCParserFactory parserFactory = new DefaultParserFactory();
    final AgentProcessHandler agentHandler =
            new AgentProcessHandler(bootstrap, logFiles, parserFactory);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(new ObjectEncoder(), agentHandler);
        }
    });
    bootstrap.connect().awaitUninterruptibly();
}

private static void configurePolling(ServerConfig cfg, String host, int port) {
    final int frequency = cfg.getParameter(Integer.class, "frequency");
    final NioClientSocketChannelFactory channelFactory =
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(newCachedThreadPool(), newCachedThreadPool());
    final ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);
    bootstrap.setOption("remoteAddress", new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    final GcParserSupplier parserSupplier = new GcParserSupplier();
    final ConcurrentMap<File, Tailer> tailerMap = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener = new ExceptionListener();
    final Set<File> discoveredSet = Sets.newHashSet();
    final File directory = new File(cfg.getParameter(String.class, "logDirectory"));

    final TailManager tailManager =
            new TailManager(discoveredSet, tailerMap, parserSupplier, exceptionListener, localHostName);
    final DetectionTask detectionTask = new DetectionTask(directory, discoveredSet, tailManager);

    final FileWatcher fileWatcher =
            new FileWatcher(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1), detectionTask, frequency);
    final Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
    final EfxAgentHandler agentHandler =
            new EfxAgentHandler(bootstrap, tailManager, fileWatcher, timer);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(new ObjectEncoder(), agentHandler);
        }
    });
    bootstrap.connect().awaitUninterruptibly();
}

private static List<File> logFiles(ServerConfig cfg, String[] args) {
    String logDir = cfg.getParameter(String.class, "logDirectory");
    final int n = args.length;
    List<File> logFiles = new ArrayList<File>(n-3);
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        String filePath = logDir + args[i] + ".gc.log";
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                logger.info("missing log file so creating empty file at path: " + filePath);
                File dir = file.getParentFile();
                dir.mkdirs();
                if (file.createNewFile())
                    logger.info("successfully created empty file at path: " + filePath);
            }
            logFiles.add(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("error creating log file at path: " + filePath);
        }
    }
    return logFiles;
}

static final class AgentPauseListener implements GCEventListener<CMSType, CMSHeap> {
    private final Channel channel;
    private final GcEventsPersister.Builder builder;
    private byte state;

    private AgentPauseListener(Channel channel,
                               GcEventsPersister.Builder builder) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(PauseDetail<CMSType> pauseDetail) {
        logger.info("onPause");
        checkState(state == 0x00 || state == 0x01);
        builder
                .collectionType(pauseDetail.getType() == null
                        ? null : pauseDetail.getType().toString())
                .start(new Instant(pauseDetail.getStartTimestamp()))
                .end(new Instant(pauseDetail.getEndTimestamp()))
                .pause(pauseDetail.getType() == null
                        ? false : pauseDetail.getType().isPause())
                .duration(pauseDetail.getPauseMillis());
        if (state == 0x00)
            channel.write(builder.build());
        else
            state |= 0x02;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeapBefore(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> details) {
        logger.info("onHeapBefore");
        checkState(state == 0x00);
        builder.heapBefore(used(details)).heapBeforeTotal(total(details));
        state |= 0x01;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeapAfter(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> details) {
        logger.info("onHeapAfter");
        checkState(state == 0x03);
        builder.heapAfter(used(details)).heapAfterTotal(total(details));
        channel.write(builder.build());
        state = 0x00;
    }

    private final long used(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> details) {
        return used(details, CMSHeap.PAR_NEW_GENERATION)
                + used(details, CMSHeap.CMS_GENERATION)
                + used(details, CMSHeap.CMS_PERM_GENERATION);
    }

    private final long used(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> heapDetail,
                            CMSHeap gen) {
        final Map<CMSHeap, HeapDetail.HeapMetric> sizes = heapDetail.getSizes();
        final long used = sizes.get(gen).getUsed();
        logger.info("used = " + used);
        return used;
    }

    private final long total(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> details) {
        return total(details, CMSHeap.PAR_NEW_GENERATION)
                + total(details, CMSHeap.CMS_GENERATION)
                + total(details, CMSHeap.CMS_PERM_GENERATION);
    }

    private final long total(HeapDetail<CMSHeap> heapDetail,
                             CMSHeap gen) {
        final Map<CMSHeap, HeapDetail.HeapMetric> sizes = heapDetail.getSizes();
        return sizes.get(gen).getTotal();
    }
}

static final class ExceptionListener implements ParseExceptionListener {
    @Override
    public void onParseError(int lineNo, String input, String error) {
        logger.error("error parsing: " + lineNo + " - " + input + " - " + error);
    }
}

static final class ReconnectTask implements TimerTask {
    private final ClientBootstrap bootstrap;

    ReconnectTask(ClientBootstrap bootstrap) {
        this.bootstrap = bootstrap;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Timeout timeout) throws Exception {
        bootstrap.connect();
    }
}

static class AgentProcessHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    private final ClientBootstrap bootstrap;
    private final List<File> logFiles;
    private final GCParserFactory parserFactory;
    private final Set<Tailer> tailers = new HashSet<Tailer>(4);

    public AgentProcessHandler(ClientBootstrap bootstrap,
                               List<File> logFiles,
                               GCParserFactory parserFactory) {
        this.bootstrap = bootstrap;
        this.logFiles = logFiles;
        this.parserFactory = parserFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        logger.info("channel connected");
        for (File logFile : logFiles) {
            logger.info("setting up scraper for logfile: " + logFile);
            GCParser parser = parserFactory.getParser();
            GcEventsPersister.Builder builder =
                    new GcEventsPersister.Builder(logFile.getName(), localHostName);
            GCEventListener gcEventListener =
                    new AgentPauseListener(e.getChannel(), builder);
            TailerListener listener =
                    new LogLineListener(parser, gcEventListener, exceptionListener);
            Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(logFile, listener, 1000L, true);
            tailers.add(tailer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        logger.error("channel disconnected");
        stopTailers();
        scheduleReconnect();
    }

    private void scheduleReconnect() {
        timer.newTimeout(new ReconnectTask(bootstrap), 5L,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private final void stopTailers() {
        for (Tailer tailer : tailers) {
            tailer.stop();
        }
        tailers.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        logger.error(cause);
        if (cause instanceof ConnectException) {
            stopTailers();
            scheduleReconnect();
        }
    }
};

private static class LogLineListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    private final GCParser parser;
    private final GCEventListener pauseListener;
    private final ParseExceptionListener exceptionLister;

    public LogLineListener(GCParser parser,
                           GCEventListener listener,
                           ParseExceptionListener exceptionLister) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.pauseListener = listener;
        this.exceptionLister = exceptionLister;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        logger.info("handle(String line)");
        parser.matchLine(line, pauseListener, exceptionLister);
    }
}

private static final class GcParserSupplier
        implements Supplier<GCParser<CMSType, CMSHeap>> {
    @Override public GCParser<CMSType, CMSHeap> get() {
        return new CMSParser();
    }
}

private static final class TailManager implements FileHandler {
    private final Set<File> discoveredSet;
    private final ConcurrentMap<File, Tailer> tailerMap;
    private final Supplier<GCParser<CMSType, CMSHeap>> parserSupplier;
    private final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener;
    private final String host;
    private volatile boolean go;

    private TailManager(final Set<File> discoveredSet,
                        final ConcurrentMap<File, Tailer> tailerMap,
                        final Supplier<GCParser<CMSType, CMSHeap>> parserSupplier,
                        final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener,
                        final String host) {
        this.discoveredSet = discoveredSet;
        this.tailerMap = tailerMap;
        this.parserSupplier = parserSupplier;
        this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener;
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void stop() {
        go = false;
        for (Tailer tailer : tailerMap.values())
            tailer.stop();
        tailerMap.clear();
    }

    public void start() {
        go = true;
    }

    @Override public void onNew(final File file,
                                final Channel channel) {
        checkState(go);
        GCParser<CMSType, CMSHeap> parser = parserSupplier.get();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        GcEventsPersister.Builder builder =
                new GcEventsPersister.Builder(fileName, host);
        AgentPauseListener eventListener =
                new AgentPauseListener(channel, builder);
        Function<Void, Void> removeTail = new Function<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void apply(@Nullable final Void input) {
                final Tailer tailer = tailerMap.remove(file);
                tailer.stop();
                discoveredSet.remove(file);
                return null;
            }
        };
        GcTailAdaptor listener =
                new GcTailAdaptor(logger, parser, eventListener, exceptionListener, removeTail);
        tailerMap.put(file, Tailer.create(file, listener, 1000L, true));
    }

    @Override public void onDelete(File file, Channel channel) {
        checkState(go);
        final Tailer tailer = tailerMap.remove(file);
        tailer.stop();
    }
}

static class EfxAgentHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    private final ClientBootstrap bootstrap;
    private final TailManager tailManager;
    private final FileWatcher fileWatcher;
    private final Timer timer;

    public EfxAgentHandler(ClientBootstrap bootstrap,
                           TailManager tailManager,
                           FileWatcher fileWatcher,
                           Timer timer) {
        this.bootstrap = bootstrap;
        this.tailManager = tailManager;
        this.fileWatcher = fileWatcher;
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @Override public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                           ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        logger.info("channel connected");
        tailManager.start();
        fileWatcher.start(e.getChannel());
    }

    @Override public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                              ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        logger.error("channel disconnected");
        tailManager.stop();
        fileWatcher.stop();
        scheduleReconnect();
    }

    private void scheduleReconnect() {
        timer.newTimeout(new ReconnectTask(bootstrap), 5L,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                          ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        logger.error(cause);
        if (cause instanceof ConnectException) {
            tailManager.stop();
            scheduleReconnect();
        }
    }
}

static final class GcTailAdaptor extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    private final Logger logger;
    private final GCParser parser;
    private final GCEventListener eventListener;
    private final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener;
    private final Function<Void, Void> removeTail;
    private volatile long lastTail;

    GcTailAdaptor(final Logger logger,
                  final GCParser parser,
                  final GCEventListener eventListener,
                  final ParseExceptionListener exceptionListener, 
                  final Function<Void, Void> removeTail) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.parser = parser;
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
        this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener;
        this.removeTail = removeTail;
    }

    @Override public void handle(String line) {
        lastTail();
        parser.matchLine(line, eventListener, exceptionListener);
    }

    private final void lastTail() {
        final long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (lastTail == 0L) {
            lastTail = t;
            return;
        }
        if ((t-lastTail)>=1800000L) 
            removeTail.apply(null);
    }

    @Override public void handle(Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
    }
}

@VisibleForTesting
final static class DetectionTask implements Runnable {
    private final File directory;
    private final Set<File> discovered;
    private final FileHandler handler;
    private volatile Channel channel;

    DetectionTask(final File directory,
                  final Set<File> discovered,
                  final FileHandler handler) {
        this.discovered = discovered;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public boolean removeStaleFile(File file) {
        checkArgument(discovered.contains(file), 
                "file is not discovered so cannot be stale");
        return discovered.remove(file);
    }

    public void run() {
        final File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i=0, n=files.length; i<n; i++) {
            final File file = files[i];
            synchronized (discovered) {
                if (!discovered.contains(file)) {
                    discovered.add(file);
                    handler.onNew(file, channel);
                }
            }                               
        }
        final ImmutableSet<File> logFiles = ImmutableSet.copyOf(files);
        final ImmutableSet<File> diff = Sets.difference(discovered, logFiles).immutableCopy();
        for (File file : diff) {
            discovered.remove(file);
            handler.onDelete(file, channel);
        }
    }
}


@VisibleForTesting static interface FileHandler {
    void onNew(File file, Channel channel);
    void onDelete(File file, Channel channel);
}

@VisibleForTesting
final static class FileWatcher {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private final DetectionTask detectionTask;
    private final int frequency;
    private volatile ScheduledFuture<?> task;

    @VisibleForTesting
    FileWatcher(ScheduledExecutorService executor,
                DetectionTask detectionTask,
                int frequency) {
        this.executor = executor;
        this.detectionTask = detectionTask;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public void start(Channel chanel) {
        task = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(detectionTask, 0L, frequency, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        detectionTask.setChannel(chanel);
    }

    public void stop() {
        task.cancel(true);
        detectionTask.setChannel(null);
    }

    public static FileWatcher on(File directory,
                                 FileHandler handler,
                                 int frequency) {
        checkNotNull(directory);
        checkNotNull(handler);
        checkArgument(directory.isDirectory(), "file is not a directory");
        checkArgument(directory.canRead(), "no read access to directory");
        checkArgument(0 < frequency, "frequency must be > 0");
        final HashSet<File> objects = Sets.newHashSet();
        final DetectionTask task = new DetectionTask(directory, objects, handler);
        final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        return new FileWatcher(executorService, task, frequency);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Edited to add the agent and collector code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered why this happens. I am using a deprecated ObjectDecoder that's not compatible with my client's ObjectEncoder. I am just sending a ByteBuffer instead and it's fine now.

Answer (score 1):

> I have incorrect code somewhere.

Correct. Specifically, you almost certainly have different ObjectInput/OutputStream lifetimes at server and client. Use the same streams for the life of the socket, and don't do any I/O over those sockets via any other means.

Comment: I'm not touching any OutputStreams outside of netty. I do however use only one connection to send serialized Java objects from different threads - is that an issue?

Comment: @algolicious Almost certainly, unless they are carefully synchronized at both ends.